# $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, f \in C^{n}$, if $f(a)=f'(a)=...=f^{(n)}(a)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, f \in C^{n}$, if $f(a)=f'(a)=...=f^{(n)}(a)=0$, then, for $k \leq n$ exists $\varphi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, \varphi \in C^{(n-k)}$ such that $f(x)=\varphi(x)(x-a)^k$

- I thought about taking the Taylor expasion with rest of Lagrange, 
  $$ f(x) = \frac{f^{(k)}(c(x))(x-a)^k}{n!}$$
  but do not know how to associate the function $\varphi$ with the function $\frac{f^{(k)}(c(x))}{n!}$

Comment: Taylor approximation works for this. See [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).

Comment: Use the integral form of the Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

If $k=0$, then take $\phi_0(x) = f(x)$.

If $k\ge 1$, the Taylor expansion for a $C^n$ function $f$, with $k \le n$ gives:

$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} {1 \over i!}f^{(i)}(a) (x-a)^i + \int_0^1 {1 \over (k-1)!} f^{(k)}(a + t (x-a)) (1-t)^{k-1} dt (x-a)^k$.

Since $f^{(i)}(a) = 0$, if we let
$\phi_k(x) = \int_0^1 {1 \over (k-1)!} f^{(k)}(a + t (x-a)) (1-t)^{k-1} dt$ we have
$f(x) = \phi_k(x) (x-a)^k$.

Since $f$ is $C^n$, we see that $f^{(k)}$ is $C^{n-k}$, from which it follows
that $\phi_k$ is $C^{n-k}$.

Note that the condition $f^{(n)}(a) = 0$ is superfluous.